# How to paste a DIC file without deleting the default file or overwriting existing content with Go?

Tags: file, go

I want to check the characters of a file sequentially from the beginning of the file and if a character exists in file1 and not in file2, It appends the character.

Actually I have a DIC file that I want to install on the user's computer. But I don't want existing texts to be overwritten. Also, I don't want to delete the default file on the user's computer.

This DIC file is a screen reader dictionary used for the blind.

I would be grateful if you could help me

I wrote a code that checks the character, but I couldn't write it to the file.

This is my code: https://go.dev/play/p/4ogdlQaBRHz

Note: This code may be a incorrect code.

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by os.File.Write.

Comment: Change to fo.Write(v)

Comment: @Peter I didn't understand your comment. I don't have an error but this code doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @Rahmat Fathoni I did and I got an error like this: cannot use v (variable of type byte) as type []byte in argument to fo.Write

Comment: so change to Change to fo.Write([]byte{v})

Comment: @Rahmat Fathoni I tried All of them. it doesn't work. It write seven milion spaces on my file.

Comment: simple example: https://go.dev/play/p/uHzJpOg1KUU